# Convergence of a sum of random variables with Bernoulli coefficient.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I present a problem which is connected with some of my previous questions.

Suppose that $Y_t$ is a "regular enogh" (for example $Y_t=W_t$ with $W_t$ a Brownian motion) stochastic process with $t\in[0,1]$. For all $\Delta>0$ consider a sequence of iid Bernoulli variables $B_{k\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}$ with $k=0,...,\lfloor1/\Delta\rfloor$ such that

$$
\mathbb{P}[B_{k\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}=1]=1-\lambda\,\Delta,\quad\mathbb{P}[B_{k\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}=0]=\lambda\,\Delta, \quad k=0,...,\left\lfloor1/\Delta\right\rfloor.
$$

Define, for every $t\in[0,1]$ the integer $k_t =\left\lfloor t/\Delta\right\rfloor$ which is such that $k_t\,\Delta\rightarrow t$ when $\Delta\rightarrow 0$. It is immediate (by using the notable limit $(1-\lambda\,\Delta)^{t/\Delta}\rightarrow e^{-\lambda\,t}$) to show that when $\Delta\rightarrow 0$

$$
B_{k_t\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}\,B_{(k_t-1)\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}\,\cdots B_{\delta}^{(\Delta)}\stackrel{L^1}{\longrightarrow} e^{-\lambda\,t.}\quad (1)
$$

and that

$$
1-B_{k_t\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}\stackrel{L^1}{\longrightarrow}0.\quad (2) 
$$

Now consider the following sum (I call $Y_{k_t\,\Delta}$ the stochastic process $Y_t$ in the point $t=k_t\,\Delta$)

\begin{eqnarray}
X_{k_t\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}&=&(1-B_{k_t\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)})\,Y_{k_t\,\delta}+B_{k_t\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)}\,(1-B_{(k_t-1)\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)})\,Y_{(k_t-1)\,\Delta}+\\
& &+B_{k_t\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)}\,B_{(k_t-1)\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)}\,(1-B_{(k_t-2)\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)})\,Y_{(k_t-2)\,\Delta}+\cdots+B_{k_t\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)}\cdots B_{2\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)}\,(1-B_{\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)})\,Y_{\Delta}+\\
& &+B_{k_t\,\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)}\cdots B_{\Delta}^{\left(\Delta\right)}\,Y_{0},\quad (3)
\end{eqnarray}

My problem is to find the limit (in probability or distribution) of $X_{k_t\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}$ when $\Delta$ goes to zero. My guess is that $X_{k_t\,\Delta}^{(\Delta)}$ should converge to some $X_t$ which is the pice-wise version of $Y_t$. I report
in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgOEy.png) a visual representation of what I mean. The process $Y$ is a simulated random walk (black line) while $X$ (red line) matches $Y$ at random instants and stays constant between two instants (and it is obtained using equation (3) on a fine discrete mesh). Given the structure of equation (3) and the two limits (1) and (2) I am pretty sure that the random instants should come form an arrival process with intensity $\lambda$.

Any help, even a reference, is appreciated.

[image: Black line: simulated random walk, it represents the process $Y$. Red line. Red line: my guess for the asymptotic limit of X.]